# Auto-renewal In-app Purchases free trial period and subscription amount remittance

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

In an iOS application offering IAP, When will be the money be remitted from the bank account, when subscribing a product that is offering free trial for a month.

Will it be on the first time subscription itself OR on completion of the free trial period?

Background of the story: One customer has raised concern that money was remitted on subscription itself when he has free trial period available on subscribe button click itself.Cannot find any document saying about amount remittance.

Saw in the iTunes product configuration page this will be only done on free trial completion time.Need confirmation.Please share if any supported link or document on the same.